# C# method skipping over java script call

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an ASP button that has an event listener attached to it. When pressed it calls the C# method and executes whatever code I may have within it.

I have a javascript function I want to call when the listener first executes. However, C# completely skips over the function call and moves on to the lines below it.

Here's the question: Why is it skipping over the call? And when I isolate just the call, ( have nothing in the method other than the call) IT WORKS. The very second I put another line of code below it, it stops being called. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the ASP button.

```
<asp:Button ID="crapJim" runat="server" Text="RateTest" OnClick="crapJim_Click"/>
```

And here is the C# Method

```
protected void crapJim_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "getSessionName()", true);

/* ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hwa", "getSessionName();", true);*/

   string s = hfRaterName.Value;
   Console.Write(s);
   string stop = "";
}
```

Currently have the ClientScript commented out and trying the ScriptManager. Both work individually, but not when other code is with it. What I mean by that is:

```
protected void crapJim_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "getSessionName()", true);
}
```

Just this alone will work, but any other code with it, it will no longer fire. C# skips over it.

Oh and here is the Javascript code I am using.

```
function getSessionName() {    
      var hfRaterName = prompt("Please enter your session name");
      hfRaterName.value = hfRaterName;
}
```

Comment: You're reusing `hfRaterName` for 2 things - first it's given the value of the prompt, then you change the value; and never actually get or assign the element on the page with `getElementById`.

Comment: Of course it "skips over it". That's how web applications work. Server side code is executed, then the response is sent to the client as HTML/CSS/JS. There is no browser for the JS to run in when your C# is executing. You're registering a startup script to be run after the response has been sent to the client. You need to read about server side vs client side development, and the ASP.NET Web Forms Postback model.

Comment: Thanks for the quick class mason. Makes perfect sense after reading it. I'll be sure dive deeper into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an easier way, if you don't have to use `RegisterStartupScript`.

.aspx:

```
// OnClientClick will call your javascript function first, then the code behind.
<asp:Button ID="btnPrompt" runat="server" Text="Prompt"
    OnClientClick="doPrompt();" 
    OnClick="btnPrompt_Click" />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblPromptResult" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfPrompt" runat="server" />
<br />

<script>
    function doPrompt() {
        document.getElementById("hfPrompt").value = 
            prompt("Please enter your session name");
    }
</script>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void btnPrompt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblPromptResult.Text = hfPrompt.Value;
}
```

Comment: Hey Wazz, thanks for the help. I was on a similar suggested track as your comment yesterday (which works exactly as you say it will) however, the issue I'm stuck with now is the hidden field is always empty. As a debug I am consoling out and using a C# MessageBox to show whats in the hidden field and unfortunately it's always empty. It's as if the JavaScript never assigns the prompt result to the hidden field. Any idea as to why?

Comment: Hey wazz. Thanks again for the help. I ended up figuring it out yesterday. The way you suggested worked however, something kept causing the hidden field to be blank.  No matter what I tried the Javascript took the entered prompt info by the user, but I kept getting this Null value reference error when I consoled out.   I had a similar problem before where ASP changes the control ID once compiled and launched. So I used ClientIDMode="Static" in the hidden field and it worked as it was supposed to. Thanks again. I'll post what I did if anyone ever comes across the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the case anyone else comes across this same problem. I took wazz's advice and used the OnclientClick along with Onclick. Executing the Javascript first rather than having the C# call the Javascript.

```
//This is the HiddenField used to capture the users identified session name
//which I then store in a DB and use in a few other related pages.
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" /> 

//This is the ASP button used to call both the Javascript and C# code behind  
    <asp:Button ID="btnRateBeazely" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="btnbig" Text="Rate Beazley" OnClick="btnRateBeazely_Click" OnClientClick="getSessionName();" />

//The Javascript is simple, but does exactly what I want it to. DB has character
//limit to 50 so I ensure the user can't input higher than that. Assign the input
//to the hiddenfield ID and off we go.  

function getSessionName() {

var SessionSet = prompt("Please enter your session name"); 

while (SessionSet.length > 49) {
    alert("You have too many characters. Please enter again.")
    var SessionSet = prompt("Please reenter your session name"); 
}

document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value = SessionSet;
```

}

```
//In the code behind I just assign a new string variable to the hidden field value
```